# Array like container that only stores large amounts of 1s and 0s

Tags: c++, arrays, containers, bitset

I'm trying to make a program that tells you the amount of prime numbers between 0 and n and tell you if x is a prime number. I've managed to make it work with a really big array that stores bools, but i feel like i can optimize this by using something like a bitset, but when i try to use a bitset it just crashes. I need the container to be able to store 10^8 0s and 1s.

EDIT: This segfaults for large numbers :(

EDIT 2:
---Example input---

```
9973 6
1
2
3
4
9972
9973
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned short int q;

    cin >> n >> q;

    //bitset<10^8 - 1> primes;
    bool primes[n]{false};

    for(unsigned int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = i*i; j < n; j += i)
        {
            primes[j - 1] = true; 
            //primes.set(j - 1);
        }
    }

    primes[0] = true;
    //primes.set(0);
    cout << count(primes, primes + n , false) << endl;
    //cout << primes.count() - 1 << endl;

    for(unsigned short int i = 1; i <= q; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        cout << !primes[x - 1] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Use `std::vector<bool>`. Is has a [specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) that makes it use only 1 bit per element.

Comment: Your program is invalid (you can't use user input to define the size of an array on the stack). What compiler are you using?

Comment: what is the input? What is supposed to happen when `x > n` ?

Comment: @Tharwen VLAs are an extension in some compilers (GCC and maybe Clang IIRC), it's 'valid' just not portable

Comment: @super `std::vector<bool>` still is a very bad advice since we have `std::bitset`. I don't know if boosts dynamic bitset made it's way into the standards meanwhile.

Comment: @Tharwen Im using GNU g++ for c++17. When i was using the bitset i tried specifying the size to bitset<10^8 - 1>, gave me instant seg fault aswell.

Comment: @JoelBäckström You're most likely exceeding the maximum stack size. Try creating a std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<100000000>> instead

Comment: Do you actually have `10^8-1` there? With the `^` operator?

Comment: @Ap31 Yes i was using the ^ operator.

Comment: @JoelBäckström And what do you think the `^` operator actually does?

Comment: @Ap31 ooh, yeah. That's the XOR operator. Swapped it out for 100000000! :)

Comment: @JoelBäckström Hint: Check before you use something: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Operators

Comment: @JoelBäckström Also note, that the ordinal position of the current largest prime number found is just 52 or such (cannot find the reference ATM). So 64 bits should be fairly enough, despite the fact that your code is insufficient to find a larger one anyways (your integers aren't able to hold the necessary number of digits).

Comment: @JoelBäckström Ooops, sorry about my last comment, the boolean ordinal position is of course not congruent with the ordinal position of the prime number series using the _sieve of erasthotenes_ algo. It's true for the numeric postion of a found prime, and false if the index isn't a prime. I didn't meant to unnecessarily confuse you.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Well, i've got it to not segfault using a ptr to the bitset so that it uses the heap instead of stack. However now i'm getting

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  bitset::set: __position (which is 18446744073709551615) >= _Nb (which is 100000000)
Aborted (core dumped)

when running with big numbers for n.

Comment: @JoelBäckström That's worth asking an entirely different question here.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I've updated the code in the post, is that the wrong way to go about it? Am i better off posting a new question entirely? Thanks

Comment: @JoelBäckström Don't do that please! Post an entierly new question as mentioned.